# OrientDB perform a group by on embeddedlist column

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2, orientdb-2.1

I have the following query:

```
SELECT Sub_Type, count(Sub_Type)     
FROM SOME_TABLE  
GROUP BY Sub_Type
```

Sub_Type field type is an embedded list of string

The result I'm getting is:

```
Blotter_Sub_Type | count
["A"] | 2
["B"] | 3
["C"] | 3
["A","B"] | 1
["B","C"] | 1
```

But when I'm really after is to get how many occurrences of each value, my expected result is:

```
Blotter_Sub_Type | count
"A" | 3
"B" | 5
"C" | 4
```

Meaning that it will count the occurrences of each value individually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use UNWIND and a subquery:

```
SELECT Sub_Type, count(Sub_Type) FROM (
   SELECT Sub_Type FROM SOME_TABLE UNWIND Sub_Type
) GROUP BY Sub_Type
```